# Slice a beginning of a string in C

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

```
void slice_first_char(char ** string)
{
    *string = &(*string[1]);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char * input = "abc";
    input = &(input[1]);
    puts(input); // "bc" as expected.

    slice_first_char(&input);
    puts(input); // \372\277_\377
                 // What‘s going on?
}
```

How can I rewrite a slice_first_char function to make it work as expected?

Comment: Why don't you explain what you expect it to do, and then maybe we can work out how to do it?

Comment: @NVI  you can write a custom substr() function to extract

Comment: I don't know C at all, but for fun im going to guess. Remove the "&" so it becomes `slice_first_char(input)`. As im guessing your passing a reference by reference, not a string by reference?

Comment: What does your DEBUGGER show you when you walk through it? That's the first place to start.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You got the parentheses in

```
&(*string[1]);
```

wrong. I guess you meant

```
&((*string)[1]);
```

Your original version dereferences the pointer of the first element of the `strings` array, and then takes the address of that whereas you actually want to dereference the given pointer (because it just points to a single string), then take the first element of that (the first character) and then take the address of that.

A slighty less convulated way to express this would be

```
*string + 1
```

by the way.

Comment: +1: That does the job, producing first `bc` then `c` when plugged into the program in the question.

Comment: Thanks! Spent an hour and haven’t noticed it.

Comment: This notation is pretty messy, though.  Dereferencing and then taking the address again?  Suggest pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @singpolyma: Right (please note that I took the notation from the OP, I wouldn't have written it like that). I now added a remark on how to express the same more concisely.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe right, I know.  It's fair to show him what's wrong with his, I just wanted to point out the better way also.  Thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be attempting to remove the first char from a string.  So:

```
char* remove_first_char(const char* s) {
  return (s+1);
}
```

Comment: And use it like this: `input = remove_first_char(input);`, I assume. Looks much simpler.

Comment: Or if you want to be fancy: `return *s ? s + 1 : s;`